# how to install spatial_transformer

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to run an attention model, but when I try to import spatial_transformer, it says that no module named 'spatial_transformer', so I try to use 'pip install spatial_transformer',but it comes out that 'No matching distribution found for spatialtransformer'. I search for this problem and see someone else use the same code "from spatial_transformer import SpatialTransformer", so I want to know how to install this package, thanks!

PS:my code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
import keras.backend as K
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import imresize
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, 
Conv2D
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.utils import np_utils, generic_utils
from keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD
from spatial_transformer import SpatialTransformer
#from stn.transformer import spatial_transformer_network
%matplotlib inline

np.random.seed(1337)  # for reproducibility
batch_size = 128
nb_classes = 10
nb_epoch = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the pytorch implementation instead.

It's a spatial transformer that has clear documentation and examples.

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/spatial_transformer_tutorial.html

We don't have very much information about the module you are importing here since package names aren't universal.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this line,

**from spatial_transformer import SpatialTransformer**

it could also mean import 'SpatialTransformer' from the file spatial_transformer.py. Putting it in the same directory as your python script should work.

e.g. taking this https://gist.github.com/oarriaga/8438a7276bdc2b4ff03986d465e243b3 and saving it as spatial_transformer.py.

Comment: Thank you! I will copy the script to my own file.

Answer (score 0):

You can install spatial_transformer using

```py
pip install stn
```

See [PyPI link](https://pypi.org/project/stn/#description)